# How to get a wire from the inside to the outside of a pressure vessel?

Tags: pressure

Imagine you have a pressure vessel, e.g., the hull of a deep sea submersible. A good one would be a sphere of inches thick metal. But how could I wire the inside to a component on the outside? If I were to just drill a hole straight in and thread the wire through and seal it with caulk or something, I severely doubt that could resist extreme amounts of pressure.

So how is it done?

Comment: Start by searching for bulkhead connectors and then consider pressure

Comment: To prevent crack propagation under pressure also look into reaming the hole.

Comment: Have you done an online search for `feedthrough "pressure vessel"`? Looked at the [scientific and technical literature](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=feedthrough+%22pressure+vessel%22&btnG=) on the topic ([example](https://tinyurl.com/3h67z9za))?

Comment: @Chemomechanics But how do those work?

Comment: They work pretty well, actually. (That's a joke.) Seriously, I doubt you actually reviewed the information at the links in the one minute between our comments. So why would someone make the effort to write a long answer here?